# Can I get an explanation for how optimal substructure is used to find the longest increasing subsequence in this powerpoint slide?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I'm learning about finding optimal solutions in my algorithms class at the moment and one of the topics is about finding optimal substructures in problems.

My understanding of it so far is that we see if we can find an optimal solution for a problem of size n. If we can, then we increase the size of the problem by 1 so it's n+1. If the optimal solution for n+1 includes the entire optimal solution of n plus the new solution introduced by the +1, then we have optimal substructure.

I was given an example of using optimal substructure to find the longest increasing subsequence given a set of numbers. This is shown on the powerpoint slide here:

[image: Slide]

Can someone explain to me the notation on the bottom of the slide and give me a proof that this problem can be solved using optimal substructure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Lower(i) means a set of positions `j` in `S` to the left of the current index `i` such that S<sub>j</sub> is less than S<sub>i</sub>. In other words, elements S<sub>j</sub> and S<sub>i</sub> are in increasing order, even though there may be other elements in between them.
- The expression with the brace on the left explains how we construct the answer:

  1. First line says that if the set Lower(i) is empty (i.e. S<sub>i</sub> is the largest number in the sequence so far) then the answer is 1. This is the base case: a single number is treated as one-element sequence
  2. Second line says that if Lower(i) is not empty, then we pick the max element from it, and add 1. In other words, we look to the left of the number S<sub>i</sub> for another number S<sub>j</sub> that is smaller than S<sub>i</sub>, and ends the longest ascending subsequence among Lower(i).

All of this is incredibly long way of writing these six lines of pseudocode:

```
L[0] = 1
for i = 1..N
    L[i] = 1
    for j = i..0
        if S[i] > S[j] // Member of Lower(i) ?
            L[i] = MAX(L[i], L[j]+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to **@dasblinkenlight** answer:

This is an iterative approach based on optimal substructure because at any given iteration `i`, we will figure out the length of the longest increasing subsequence ending at index `i`. Hence by the time we reach this iteration all corresponding LIS are already established for any index `j < i`.  Using this information we find the answer for index `i, i+1` and so on. Now the original question is asking for the LIS, but it has to have an ending index, so it is enough to take the maximum LIS among all indexes.

Such approach is strongly correlated with [Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) and quite broad programming/algorithm method [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

P.S.

There exists another, slightly more complicated approach, which allows to compute LIS in a more efficient way using binary search. The algorithm from the slides is `O(n^2)`, when `O(n*log(n))` algorithm does exist as well.